# regex - camel case that doesnt contain consecutive uppercase letters

Tags: regex, dfa

Consider the following description of identifiers: "Identifiers are alphanumeric, but must start with
a lowercase letter and may not contain consecutive uppercase letters."
 Write a DFA that accepts these identifiers.

this is my regex that i will use to translate to the DFA but i dont think its correct

```
[a-z].( ([a-z0-9] | [a-z0-9][A-Z])* | ([a-z0-9] | [A-Z][a-z0-9])* )
```

Comment: `[a-z] [A-Z]? ( [a-z0-9]+[A-Z] )* [a-z0-9]*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct regex is:

```
    ^[a-z][A-Z]?(([a-z0-9][A-Z]?))*$
```

first: lowercase (or number)
after the end: infinite lowercase uppercase? lowercase uppercase? lowercase uppercase?...

PS: if you write a dot in a regexp, it will match any character. To match a literal `.`, use `[.]` or `\.`.

Comment: true i forget check the numbers. ^[a-z][A-Z]?(([a-z0-9][A-Z]?))*$

Answer (score 1):

```
S -> [a-z] A
A -> [a-z0-9] A
A -> [A-Z] B
B -> [a-z0-9] A
```

S - starting state
A, B - final states